# in Login Activity if user doesn't exist in the 1st loginURL how to add another alternate URL to check in?

Tags: php, android

I have 2 tables in my database i want to link it to my login activity. but after login success i want it to open different activity according to diffrent table user... like: if user data is in table A(user_data) then after login success i want it to open activity 1 and if  user data is in table A(employee_data) then after login success i want it to open activity 2. thank for your help.

MY MainActivity.java

```js
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class));
            return;
        }

        UsernameET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_user);
        PasswordET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_pass);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        //ab.setLogo(R.mipmap.logo_mini86);
        //ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        LoginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Go_btn);
        button_reg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.register_link);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

        OnClickButtonListner();
        LoginBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void userLogin(){
        final String reg_username = UsernameET.getText().toString();
        final String reg_password = PasswordET.getText().toString();

        progressDialog.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (!obj.getBoolean("error")){
                                SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                                    .userLogin(
                                            obj.getInt("id"),
                                            obj.getString("phone"),
                                            obj.getString("username"),
                                            obj.getString("mail"),
                                            obj.getString("name")

                                    );
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                                finish();
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),obj.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        ){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("reg_username", reg_username);
                params.put("reg_password", reg_password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
    /** For Backgroundworker : disabled : 22-02-2017.
     * public void OnLogin (View view){
        String username = UsernameET.getText().toString();
        String password = PasswordET.getText().toString();
        String type = "login";

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
    } */

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == LoginBtn);
        userLogin();
    }
```

My userlogin.php for Table(user_data)

```js
<?php
require_once '../include/DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 if(isset($_POST['reg_username']) and isset($_POST['reg_password'])){
  $db = new DbOperations();

  if($db->userLogin($_POST['reg_username'], $_POST['reg_password'])){
   $user_data = $db->getUserByUsername($_POST['reg_username']);

   $response['error'] = false;
   $response['id'] = $user_data['id'];
   $response['name'] = $user_data['name'];
   $response['surname'] = $user_data['surname'];
   $response['username'] = $user_data['username'];
   $response['address'] = $user_data['address'];
   $response['pin'] = $user_data['pin'];
   $response['mail'] = $user_data['mail'];
   $response['phone'] = $user_data['phone'];
  }else{
   $response['error'] = true;
   $response['message'] = "Invalid User data";
  }
 }else{
  $response['error'] = true;
  $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
 }
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

My uselogin.php for Table(employee_data)

```js
<?php
require_once '../include/DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 if(isset($_POST['reg_username']) and isset($_POST['reg_password'])){
  $db = new DbOperations();

  if($db->emplLogin($_POST['reg_username'], $_POST['reg_password'])){
   $employee_data = $db->getEmplByUsername($_POST['reg_username']);

   $response['error'] = false;
   $response['id'] = $employee_data['id'];
   $response['name'] = $employee_data['name'];
   $response['surname'] = $employee_data['surname'];
   $response['username'] = $employee_data['username'];
   $response['address'] = $employee_data['address'];
   $response['pin'] = $employee_data['pin'];
   $response['mail'] = $employee_data['mail'];
   $response['phone'] = $employee_data['phone'];
   $response['catagory'] = $employee_data['catagory'];
  }else{
   $response['error'] = true;
   $response['message'] = "Invalid User data";
  }
 }else{
  $response['error'] = true;
  $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
 }
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

And My Dboperation.php File

```js
public function userLogin($username, $user_pass){
   $password = md5($user_pass);
   $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM user_data WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
   $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->store_result();
   return $stmt->num_rows > 0;

  }

  public function getUserByUsername($username){
   $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE username = ?");
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
   $stmt->execute();
   return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
  }
    
    public function emplLogin($username, $user_pass){
   $password = md5($user_pass);
   $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM employee_data WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
   $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->store_result();
   return $stmt->num_rows > 0;

  }

  public function getEmplByUsername($username){
   $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM employee_data WHERE username = ?");
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
   $stmt->execute();
   return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
  }
```

Comment: after first url gives error or some message that data not found then you need to call second url and check. it simple. what you need more?

Comment: you need to call if condition after $user_data = $db->getUserByUsername($_POST['reg_username']); . check $user_data got some value or not. if not generate error or you can directly call getEmplByUsername if $user_data not contains anything with getUserByUsername. Hope you understand

Comment: Hey! @Zaki Pathan sorry but i don't understand bro, can you show editing my file?

Comment: and i don't want to give error message i just want it to look into 2nd url and  then if i don't get values then i want it to give error message.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure about php code but gives idea to you hope you understand

```
    <?php
    require_once '../include/DbOperations.php';

    $response = array();

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        if(isset($_POST['reg_username']) and isset($_POST['reg_password'])){
            $db = new DbOperations();

            if($db->userLogin($_POST['reg_username'], $_POST['reg_password'])){
                $user_data = $db->getUserByUsername($_POST['reg_username']);
                  if($user_data!=0)//check here that value found in table or not
                   {
                      $response['error'] = false;
                      $response['id'] = $user_data['id'];
                      $response['name'] = $user_data['name'];
                      $response['surname'] = $user_data['surname'];
                      $response['username'] = $user_data['username'];
                      $response['address'] = $user_data['address'];
                      $response['pin'] = $user_data['pin'];
                      $response['mail'] = $user_data['mail'];
                      $response['phone'] = $user_data['phone'];
                    }else{
                      $employee_data = $db->getEmplByUsername($_POST['reg_username']);

                      $response['error'] = false;
                      $response['id'] = $employee_data['id'];
                      $response['name'] = $employee_data['name'];
                      $response['surname'] = $employee_data['surname'];
                      $response['username'] = $employee_data['username'];
                      $response['address'] = $employee_data['address'];
                      $response['pin'] = $employee_data['pin'];
                      $response['mail'] = $employee_data['mail'];
                      $response['phone'] = $employee_data['phone'];
                      $response['catagory'] = $employee_data['catagory'];

                 }else{
                      $response['error'] = true;
                      $response['message'] = "Invalid User data";
                 }
            }else{
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = "Invalid User data";
            }
        }else{
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

I don't know perfect condition of checking data in $user_data but this is idea. Hope you understand how to do it. If any question please feel free to ask

Comment: Bro, i get it... but this way i'gess you are trying to merge userlogin.php and uselogin.php then, how will it open different activity according to different table user in android...all I want is only if the user's user data is in $user_data then after login success it should open activity A and if the the user's user data is in $employee_data then after login success it should open activity B. and if the user is not register it should say "Invalid user data"? Did you get it? tell me if you need more information.

Comment: @SAMEERRAJPAL you just need to send one more field in response $response['activity']. For userlogin you can send $response['activity'] = "user"; and for employee you can send $response['activity'] = "employee"; and just fetch this parameter in android side and check weather it is userlogin or employee login. hope you properly understand this now

Comment: thanks bro for your suggestion... It worked for me with a little edit. anyways your suggestion helped me and that's what matters... thanks :) but i still need to find out how to implement this in my login activity.

Comment: welcome bro. Happy to help you :) :) if you need some further help you can comment

Comment: can you tell me how to implement this in my login_activity.

Comment: yes you can check with if conditon obj.getString("activity").toString().equals("user") So do user part otherwise employee part